# There is a data source column with no name in SSIS OLE DB Source task

Tags: t-sql, ssis

At the END of my SP that I'm calling from a data flow OLE DB Source object in SSIS I have the following code:

```
-- Get count from TEMP table #InactiveRules
SELECT @InactiveRulesCount = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM #InactiveRules)

-- Define information sent in the email
IF @InactiveRulesCount = 0
    BEGIN
        SELECT @InactiveRulesMessage = ('No EXCEPTION KO Rules Found.');
        SELECT @Message = @InactiveRulesMessage;
        SELECT @Message;
    END
ELSE
    BEGIN
        SELECT * FROM #InactiveRules;
    END
```

When I execute the data flow task I get this error when I have a count of 0 in my variable @InActiveRulesCount:

[image: NoDataSourceColumnError]

How do I create a data source column so that the TEXT is shown in my CSV file that I'm sending in an attachment via email using SSIS?

Any help/direction would be appreciated.  Thanks.

Thanks for your help MiguelH, and here is the code:

```
-- Get count from TEMP table #InactiveRules
SELECT @InactiveRulesCount = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM #InactiveRules)

-- Define information sent in the email
IF @InactiveRulesCount = 0
    BEGIN
        SELECT @InactiveRulesMessage = ('No EXCEPTION KO Rules Found.');
        SELECT @Message = @InactiveRulesMessage;
        SELECT @Message AS ProductName;
        SELECT @Message AS ChannelName;
        SELECT @Message AS StrategyCode;
        SELECT @Message AS StrategyName;
        SELECT @Message AS RuleCode;
        SELECT @Message AS RuleName;
        SELECT @Message AS [Priority];
        SELECT @Message AS IsActive;
        SELECT @Message AS [Message]; 
    END
ELSE
    BEGIN
        SELECT ProductName, ChannelName, StrategyCode, StrategyName, RuleCode, RuleName, [Priority], IsActive FROM #InactiveRules;
    END
```

Comment: The column has no name in the IF count = 0 part. Add an alias name at the end of the select. e.g. SELECT @MESSAGE AS MESSAGE.

Comment: Thanks, MiguelH.  However that generated another error:  "component "OLE DB Source" (1)" failed validation and returned validation status "VS_NEEDSNEWMETADATA".

Any suggestions?  Thanks again.

Comment: You need the same data names in the =0 part and the select * part otherwise this error will result e.g. If your SELECT * FROM #InactiveRules has columns "Rule,ID,Message" then these need to be mirrored in the =0 part. Basically assign  Message AS Rule, Message as ID, Message AS Message. I've clarified this below!

Answer (score 0):

```
IF @InactiveRulesCount = 0
BEGIN
    SELECT @InactiveRulesMessage = ('No EXCEPTION KO Rules Found.');
    SELECT @Message = @InactiveRulesMessage;
    SELECT @Message as MyRule,@Message as myID,@Message as MyMessage
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    SELECT MyRule,myID,MyMessage FROM #InactiveRules;
END
```

Comment: I did as you stated above and the SP executes in SQL Server with the same message in each column name but when I executed the data flow task that has the OLE DB Source for this SP I got an error that states: "component "OLE DB Source" (1)" failed validation and returned validation status "VS_NEEDSNEWMETADATA".

Comment: It would help if I'd checked my own code! Many apologies. See amendment above! Also, SSIS is very picky so both sets of names must be identical ... including the case of the characters.

Comment: NP.  Let me try again.  I put the code above in my original post.  Thank you.

Comment: You can use any value you like, but you might need to CAST some values if they aren't all varchar in the successful "SELECT" table e.g. ..SELECT @Message AS ProductName, cast('1' as integer) AS ChannelName,'x' AS StrategyCode,
'x' AS StrategyName,'x' AS RuleCode,'x' AS RuleName,'x' AS [Priority],
'x' AS IsActive,'x' AS [Message];

Comment: You may also need to CAST each of the varchar data items with the same length as the original table

Comment: Hey MiguelH, I tried the changes and I did not get the dialog box any more but I'm getting an error with the external columns in the SSIS side now when I execute the OLE DB Source task and I'm trying to figure out what the problem is.  Thanks.

Comment: What is the error? Does this occur after the OLE DB source or is the OLE DB source generating the error?

Comment: Trying to click on the automatically move this discussion to chat but it is not working.  At any rate, the error is occurring in the OLE DB Source object.  I'm trying to get the error right now.